# Formatting lost when link added to an image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am customizing the wordpress woocommerce product category page. I successfully added an image inline with the product name. My issue arises when I try to make the images linkable. The formatting of the image gets lost as they display bigger, not inline with the product name and with a border. More details below, can anyone help?

This is the current code:

```
    global $product;
$link = get_field('product_fiche');
$label = get_field('energy_label');
$full = get_field('full_energy_label');
?>

<div class="price-wrapper <?php if($link || $label) { echo 'has-col'; } ?>">
    <?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
        <span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(is_product_category() && $link || $label) : ?>
        <span class="product-action">
            <?php if($link) { echo '<a class="link" href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">Product Fiche</a>'; } ?>
            <?php if($label) { echo '<img class="energy-label" src="'.$label.'" alt="energy label" />'; } ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

This is how the category pages appear: (please note how the icons appear inline with the product name)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYdtz.png)

This is the updated code, I formatted the addition in bold.

```
global $product;
$link = get_field('product_fiche');
$label = get_field('energy_label');
$full = get_field('full_energy_label');
?>

<div class="price-wrapper <?php if($link || $label) { echo 'has-col'; } ?>">
    <?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
        <span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(is_product_category() && $link || $label) : ?>
        <span class="product-action">
            <?php if($link) { echo '<a class="link" href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">Product Fiche</a>'; } ?>
            <?php if($label) { echo '**<a href="'.$full.'" target="_blank">**<img class="energy-label" src="'.$label.'" alt="energy label" />**</a>**'; } ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

The above code leads to the below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBiY0.png)

Comment: Use your browser dev tools, and check what formatting applies to those images and/or the links wrapped around them now.

Comment: @CBroe can't some css be added to overwrite any css that's breaking the formatting? I can't understand why adding a link tag with no css is breaking...

Comment: _"can't some css be added to overwrite any css that's breaking the formatting?"_ - probably, but to determine what that would need to be, you need to figure out what styling currently applies that _does_ break it, first of all. _"I can't understand why adding a link tag with no css is breaking..."_ - there might be formatting applied from the page stylesheet, based on the `link` class, or simply based on the DOM structure and relation elements have to each other. Like I said - use your browser dev tools, and find out.